# Fill a matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

With the following code I have obtained the following contour map:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(431)
y = np.arange(225)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
values = df["Appearance_percentage"].values
values2d = np.reshape(values, (431, 225))
ax.set_ylim(225, 0)

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
ax.set_title('Mapa contour de probabilitat de trobar núvols')
plt.contour(X, Y, values2d, 30, cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig("contourmap.png")
```

[image: contour map]

I would like to know if I could fill the areas between the lines so that there are no white spaces in the color bar and the map is more attractive.

I tried doing `df["Appearance_percentage_contourmap"] = round(df["Appearance_percentage"])` and then `values = df["Appearance_percentage_contourmap"].values` and I'm still obtaining the same map with lots of white areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `plt.contour` with `plt.contourf`, where the "f" at the end means "fill".

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
values = np.outer(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.contourf(X, Y, values, 30, cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Filled contour plot.]

You may also want to emphasis the contour lines with:

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
values = np.outer(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c1 = plt.contourf(X, Y, values, 30, cmap='RdGy')
c2 = plt.contour(X, Y, values, 30, cmap='Greys')
plt.colorbar(c1)
```

[image: Filled contour plot with contour lines.]

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I define a color of the contour lines to black for example?

Comment: Replace the `cmap` parameter with `colors` and pass it the color u need, e.g. the letter 'k' for black: `plt.contour( ..., colors='k')`.

Comment: Sorry Max, the last question I have is if it's possible to control the contour lines thickness... Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Use the `linewidths` parameter. For further info, please check out the [`plt.contour` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html).

Answer (score 1):

`plt.contour()` creates an [isoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) connecting all the places with an equal interpolated value. So, it searches places where the appearance is e.g. 6% and connects these with a line.  If you set `levels=30` there will be 30 such lines drawn. `plt.contour()` does a lot of effort to create a colorbar that shows the value for each line. If you don't want such a colorbar, you can create a custom colorbar using the same values.

You can create a custom colorbar as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(431)
y = np.arange(225)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
values = np.random.randn(431, 225).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
values -= values.min()
values2d = np.reshape(values, (431, 225))
ax.set_ylim(225, 0)

plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
ax.set_title('Mapa contour de probabilitat de trobar núvols')
plt.contour(X, Y, values2d, 30, cmap='RdGy')
sm = ScalarMappable(norm=plt.Normalize(values.min(), values.max()), cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS:Please don't round the values (as in `df["Appearance_percentage_contourmap"] = round(df["Appearance_percentage"])`), because that introduces artificial inaccuracies.